# Why is it that declaring the viewBox for an SVG is different than declaring it on the symbol element with the SVG element having proper dimensions?

Tags: html, svg

So, I have a svg that is 617 units wide and 617 units long. So, with my current understanding of how svgs work, I would expect doing this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 300">
...
</svg>
```

Would be the same result as:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 617 617>
  <symbol id="testSym" viewBox="0 0 200 300">
  ...
  </symbol>
  <use href="#testSym"></use>
</svg>
```

And while the results are similar, they do differ. I'm just curious as to why? I would think, because the parent svg's viewBox is encompassing the whole graphic, using "0 0 200 300" of that would be the same as just declaring it with the svg. Help with understanding this would be greatly appreciated!

PS I know it's not generally smart to define the viewBox on the symbol element, I'm doing this just for the purpose of understanding how svgs work.

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined view boxes would make svg zoomed out in the second case.
ViewBox is applied to the container element and everything inside will be drawn considering the parent.

Comment: Hm, yeah, I'm aware of that, but the parent's viewBox of "0 0 617 617" is the whole graphic, so "0 0 200 300" of the whole graphic should be theoretically be the same as the first example, without the symbol element, because I'm in effect saying do "0 0 200 300" of the whole graphic, and since the 2nd example is getting "0 0 200 300" of the whole graphic, shouldn't they get the same area of the graphic? I can see how the second example would be zoomed out, but it should show the exact same area, just smaller. In my case though, it is showing more of the total graphic area.

Comment: Nevermind, I did some more testing on my own, and I think I understand now.